# Standard for uploads into a server directory?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I have a topic/question concerning your upload filename standards, if any, that you are using. Imagine you have an application that allows many types of documents to be uploaded to your server and placed into a directory. Perhaps the same document could even be uploaded twice. Usually, you have to make some kind of unique filename adjustment when saving the document. Assume it is saved in a directory, not saved directly into a database. Of course, the Meta Data would probably need to be saved into the database. Perhaps the typical PHP upload methods could be the application used; simple enough to do.

Possible Filenaming Standard:

1.) Append the document filename with a unique id:  image.png changed to image_20110924_ahd74vdjd3.png

2.) Perhaps use a UUID/GUID and store the actual file type (meta) in a database:  2dea72e0-a341-11e0-bdc3-721d3cd780fb

3.) Perhaps a combination: image_2dea72e0-a341-11e0-bdc3-721d3cd780fb.png

Can you recommend a good standard approach?
Thanks, Jeff

Comment: I imagine you can use any approach you would like; as long as you are consistent and it makes sense you should just use what you prefer.

Comment: How do you serve that files? Via script or directly by web-server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always just hash the file using `md5()` or `sha1()` and use that as a filename.

E.g.

3059e384f1edbacc3a66e35d8a4b88e5.ext

And I would save the original filename in the database may I ever need it.

This will make the filename unique AND it makes sure you don't have the same file multiple times on your server (since they would have the same hash).

**EDIT**

As you can see I had some discussion with zerkms about my solution and he raised some valid points.

I would always serve the file through PHP instead of letting user download them directly.

This has some advantages:

1. I would add records into the database if users upload a file. This would contain the user who uploaded the file, the original filename and tha hash of the file.
2. If a user wants to delete a file you just delete the record of the user with that file.
3. If no more users has the file after delete you can delete the file itself (or keep it anyway).
4. You should not keep the files somewhere in the document root, but rather somewhere else where it isn't accessible by the public and serve the file using PHP to the user.

A disadvantage as zerkms has pointed out is that serving files through PHP is more resource consuming, although I find the advantages to be worth the extra resources.

Another thing zerkms has pointed out is that the extension isn't really needed when saving the file as hash (since it already is in the database), but I always like to know what kind of files are in the directory by simply doing a `ls -la` for example. However again it isn't really necessarily.

Comment: What if some user uploaded the file wants to delete his file?

Comment: @zerkms: What about it? Why wouldn't the user be able to?

Comment: if 1 user uploaded file with contents `1` wants to delete it, but other 100 users who uploaded it too (remember, you proposed to store the files with the same content once) don't - how would it be possible?

Comment: what "It"? If you serve files directly from filesystem by your webserver and file has the url: `http://domain.tld/file/3059e384f1edbacc3a66e35d8a4b88e5.ext` -- how is it possible to delete it (if only 1 of 101 owners of this file wanted to delete it)?!

Comment: Add all the 'uploads' to the database along with the users the 'uploaded' the file. It's basically how for example dropbox works.

Comment: You didn't answer my question - do you propose to serve files from fs by webserver directly or by script? If by webserver - you'll not be able to "delete" file, if by script - you don't need to store extention in fs.

Comment: @zerkms: I would store it script. And you are right the the extension is not really needed (since we have the original filename in database). But I just like to see what files are in a folder but it is indeed definitively not needed.

Comment: ok, if you intended to serve files by script (which adds some more control but *much more* resources consuming) - then there is no issue and you can easily "remove" file by deleting the row from table. And keeping extention as-is could create some possible vulnerabilities in case when files are stored under web-root (I'm sure you know it but probably further readers don't)

Comment: @zerkms: updated my answer to reflect your concerns and improvements.

Comment: Wow, this question really got on a roll - even without me. Concerning the MD5, wouldn't there be a slim possibility of a duplicate? I'm thinking that a UUID would be better, especially in my situation where multiple sites may share the files from a Cloud Files server. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: @jjwdesign: If you worry about collisions you can just use `sha1()` which produces a 160 bit hash. `UUID` (v5) also uses `sha1()` but it truncates the hash to 128 bit.